# loading .doc .docx file into flex component from javascript which is called from flex actionscript

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, mime, .doc

I can load a pdf file into a flex component by calling the following javascript from actionscript:

```
document.getElementById("pdfFrame").innerHTML = "<object id='pdfIFrame'    data='"+url+"'  type='application/pdf'>  </object>";
```

I pass this function a URL indicating the location of the pdf file which is to be loaded.

This is working fine.

Now, i want to use same method for loading .doc and .docx files, so i am changed the type to 'application/msword', which is the MIME type for Word files. I have confirmed this for my file. But the Word file is not getting loaded .

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: Do you know for certain your component has the ability to parse and display Word documents in the first place?

Comment: I am sorry but I dont know that but i did not do anything special for adding ability for pdf too..but it works for it...basically i am trying to set innerHTML to the content i am sending which in first case was pdf.so, by that logic changing content type 'application/msword' should load word file.